# how to get client id of asp control (_lblCouncils ) in side a repeater control?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

how to get client id of the asp control  (_lblCouncils ) in side a repeater control?

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <div id="NotificationDiv">
            <asp:Label ID="_lblRoleType" Text='<%#Eval("RoleType")%>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="_lblCouncils" Text='<%#Eval("CouncilData")%>' runat="server" onclick="Name(this)"></asp:Label>

    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Why you want to get the client id of `_lblCouncils` which is already in the repeater? What you are trying to acheive?

Comment: Get it where? Server side? Client side? We can't help without more details.

Comment: @ShadowWizard  I wanna get the client side id in the client side javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to handle the OnRowDataBound(if the container control is a GridView), or ItemDataBound event(if the container control is a Repeater), then find the control:

**C#:**

```
Labeb lbl = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("_lblRoleType");
```

**VB:**

```
Dim lbl as Label = CType(e.Item.FindControl("_lblRoleType"),Label)
```